# Quickest way to convert a VB.Net desktop application to a mobile web application?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-interface, mobile

I have an application that is written in VB.NET, using the System.Windows.Forms.Form as the front-end GUI.

It runs perfectly on my Windows machine however recently there is a business requirement to convert this application to run as a web application so that people could view them in their blackberries when they go to the URL.

Is there any quick way to perform such a conversion or I will have to translate the code line-by-line for such cases?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any quick way to perform such a conversion

No, not that meets your requirements.  You can build custom winforms controls that can be hosted in internet explorer, but that won't help users accessing your app from a blackberry.

> will I have to translate the code line-by-line for such cases?

No, it's much worse than that.  Many of the things you do in a Winforms app just won't translate to the web well.  You'll have to re-write and re-think a lot of your existing code.  Essentially, you're not only re-building the app from *from scratch*, but you're doing it for a platform with which you have no prior experience.  In other words, it might even take *longer* than building the original.

I know it's not what you were hoping to hear, but thems the breaks.

Comment: This actually sounds terrible, is it possible for me to use the application as a DLL so that it at least save me some trouble coding the back-end?

Comment: Your back-end won't need to be reprogrammed if you separated it out correctly into separate assemblies.

Comment: i think my best bet is to give up then haha